# static, Java is pass by value. then why my program show that output?

Tags: java, pass-by-value

First of all Sorry For this question. this is very old topic.
Yes i did lots of search that java is pass by value.
But by my program show that out put. i can't understand  why?
My program is

```
class Dog{
    static String dogName;
    Dog(String name){
        dogName=name;
    }
    public void setName(String newName){
        dogName=newName;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return dogName;
    }
}
class JavaIsPassByValue{
    public static void main(String arr[]){
        Dog dog1=new Dog("OldDog");
        new JavaIsPassByValue().display(dog1);
        System.out.println(dog1.getName());
    }
    public void display(Dog d){
        System.out.println(d.getName());
        d = new Dog("NewDog");
        System.out.println(d.getName());
     }
}
```

Output  is
`OldDog`
`NewDog`
`NewDog`
but i am expecting
`OldDog`
`NewDog`
`OldDog`
Please anybody tell me where i am thinking wrong.

Comment: You have made `dogName` a `static` member...

Comment: In your case, `dogName` is `static`. For pass by value and pass by reference, http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/08/24/pass-by-value-or-pass-by-reference/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that your using `static` for DogName.

Hence when you call the constructor of Dog, you are changing the value of DogName for all Dog objects (as there is only one value actually).

```
static String dogName;
    Dog(String name){
        dogName=name;
    }
```

Change your code to this:

```
   String dogName;
    Dog(String name){
        dogName=name;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
static String dogName;
```

should be

```
String dogName;
```

Both objects with static share the same dogName (class level field).

Though two objects, and pass-by-value, the single object dogName was changed.

Answer (score 2):

A huge hint: remove the **static** modifier from the **Dog**'s dogName field and you will get what you expect. A general word of advice: Be careful with the static modifier

Your **Dog** class should be like this:

```
class Dog{
    private String dogName;
    Dog(String name){
        dogName=name;
    }
    public void setName(String newName){
        dogName=newName;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return dogName;
    }
}
```

As for your "pass-by-value" experiment, may I suggest that rather than printing the **dogName**, just print the object reference. In other words modify your test like this:

```
class JavaIsPassByValue{
    public static void main(String arr[]){
        Dog dog1=new Dog("OldDog");
        new JavaIsPassByValue().display(dog1);
        System.out.println("dog1: " + dog1);
    }
    public void display(Dog d){
        System.out.println("d in moment 1: " + d.getName());
        d = new Dog("NewDog");
        System.out.println("d in moment 2: " + d.getName());
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that always Object references are passed by value in Java. saying that output behavior is  because of using `static` variable and assigning it in constructor.

```
static String dogName;
```

Because it is static variable when new `Dog` instance is created previous `dogName` gets overwritten with newer value hence you see that output.

If you replace  it with

```
private String dogName;
```

you should see intended result

---

Tip: Its useful to use `this` keyword to catch such errors during compilation

```
Dog(String name){
    this.dogName=name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you declared

```
static String dogName;
```

as `static` in class Dog, there will be only one variable for 
all Dog objects, and not a variable for every instance.

You can solve you problem by simply removing the `static` keyword,
and it will work as expected.